# Trying to save list data to reuse while testing python scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, scripting

I have a python script that goes out and pulls a huge chunk of JSON data and then iterates it to build 2 lists

```
# Get all price data
response = c.get_price_history_every_minute(symbol)

# Build prices list
prices = list()
for i in range (len(response.json()["candles"])):
    prices.append (response.json()["candles"][i]["prices"])

# Build times list
times = list()
for i in range (len(response.json()["candles"])):
    times.append (response.json()["candles"][i]["datetime"])
```

This works fine, but it takes a LONG time to pull in all of the data and build the lists.  I am doing some testing trying to build out a complex script, and would like to save these two lists to two files, and then import the data from those files and recreate the lists when I run subsequent tests to skip generating, iterating and parsing the JSON.

I have been trying the following:

```
# Write Price to a File
a_file = open("prices7.txt", "w")
content = str(prices)
a_file.write(content)
a_file.close()
```

And then in future scripts:

```
# Load Prices from File
prices_test = array('d')
a_file = open("prices7.txt", "r")
prices_test = a_file.read()
```

The outputs from my json lists and the data loaded into the list created from the file output look identical, but when I try to do anything with the data loaded from a file it is garbage...

```
print (prices)
{The output looks like this} [69.73, 69.72, 69.64, ... 69.85, 69.82, etc]
print (prices_test)  
The output looks identical
```

If I run a simple query like:

```
print (prices[1], prices[2])
I get the expected output {69.73, 69.72]
```

If I do the same on the list created from the file:

```
print (prices_test[1], prices_test[2])
I get the output ( [,6 )
```

It is pulling every character in the string individually instead of using the comma separated values as I would have expected...

I've googled every combination of search terms I could think of so any help would be GREATLY appreciated!!

Comment: What does `json()` method does? It reads the file, parse JSON, then returns it as python data?

Comment: If that's what it does, you should take it out of each for-loop, it would take much less time to iterate over each loop if you store `json()` value into a variable, before starting each for-loop.

Comment: I simplified the process so that I could copy and paste the full output from both lists... 

(the list created from the actual JSON query):
print (prices)
[69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5]
print (prices[0], prices[1])
69.5, 69.5

The output from the list created from the file:
print (prices_test)
[69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5, 69.5]
print (prices_test[0], prices_test[1])
[,6

Comment: When writing to each file, why not use python `json` API to convert each list into a JSON string, using `json.dumps()`? Then when you would read the file, simply use `json.loads()` from the file's contents.

Comment: @CarlHR I am taking thousands and thousands of lines returned from the JSON response and pulling out 2 pieces of data.  The JSON returned looks like this

{
  "candles": [
    {
      "open": 71.5,
      "high": 71.5,
      "low": 71.5,
      "close": 71.5,
      "volume": 3723,
      "datetime": 1656509400000
    },

Repeated thousands of times with new information in each entry

Comment: I get it, I'm not telling you to convert the entire `response` structure into json to save it  locally. I'm telling you that you can pass any kind of structure into a json string, then get it back. So, why not using this method of storing / retrieving data into `prices` and `times` lists? Even reading simple lists like them takes a huge amount of time?

Comment: @CarlHR the honest answer is I don't know how to use json.dumps and json.loads.  I have seen them referenced in a few articles while I was searching, but I wasn't sure how to pull the info I was looking for using those.

I am also doing A to B comparisons on the data, and if I pull the price history every time I modify the overall script the data changes.  I would like to be able to run the same data through different scenarios over and over again and see how the results differ.

Comment: It's very simple. Take a data structure, a dictionary for example. Using `json.dumps({"a": "bc"})` converts the data into a json string, returning `'{"a": "bc"}'`. Now, once you have the string, simply write that to the file. Once you need the data back, read the json string, and use `json.loads(file_data)`. It will return the Dictionary read to use.

Comment: The process that takes forever is

 # Build prices list
prices = list()
for i in range (len(response.json()["candles"])):
    prices.append (response.json()["candles"][i]["prices"])

Everything else in the script runs quickly.  It looks like python is only using 1 CPU which pegs at 100%, and uses close to 8MB of memory (I have 64MB so that is not a bottle neck, it seems CPU is where the processing gets hung up)

Comment: The reason it takes too much time, is because you're calling `response.json()` on every single iteration inside the for-loop. Just call `response.json()` once outside of the loop. Store the value on a variable, then use the variable whenever `response.json()` appears on your script. The json value will not change, unless you call `response = c.get_price_history_every_minute(symbol)` again, which you don't, when you build both `prices` and `times` lists.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something like this before. I used pickle to do it.

```
import pickle

def pickle_the_data(pickle_name, list_to_pickle):
    """This function pickles a given list.

    Args:
        pickle_name (str): name of the resulting pickle.
        list_to_pickle (list): list that you need to pickle
    """
    with open(pickle_name +'.pickle', 'wb') as pikd:
        pickle.dump(list_to_pickle, pikd)
        file_name = pickle_name + '.pickle'
        print(f'{file_name}: Created.')

def unpickle_the_data(pickle_file_name):
    """This will unpickle a pickled file

    Args:
        pickle_file_name (str): file name of the pickle

    Returns:
        list: when we pass a pickled list, it will return an
        unpickled list.
    """
    with open(pickle_file_name, 'rb') as pk_file:
        unpickleddata = pickle.load(pk_file)
    return unpickleddata
```

so first pickle your list `pickle_the_data(name_for_pickle, your_list)`
then when you need to load the list `unpickle_the_data(name_of_your_pickle_file)`

Comment: response = c.get_quote(symbol)
#print (response.json())
for i in range (len(response.json()[symbol])):
    prices.append (response.json()[symbol]["closePrice"])

def pickle_the_data(prices_pickle, prices):
    """This function pickles a given list.

    Args:
        pickle_name (str): name of the resulting pickle.
        list_to_pickle (list): list that you need to pickle
    """
    with open(prices_pickle +'.pickle', 'wb') as pikd:
        pickle.dump(prices, pikd)
        file_name = prices_pickle + '.pickle'
        print ("whodat")
        print(f'{file_name}: Created.')

Comment: I tried entering this code and it seems to be doing nothing.... no error, no files created.... What am I missing?

Comment: You must call the function as well. Only defining it on the script will do nothing.

Comment: Just check out my answer: `pickle_the_data(pickle_name, list_to_pickle)` is used the same way as my `saveData(filename, data)` function.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I'm trying to explain into the comments section. Note I replaced `response.json()` to `jsonData`, successfully taking it out of each for-loop, and reduced both loops into a single one for more efficiency. Now the code should run faster.

```
import json

def saveData(filename, data):
    # Convert Data to a JSON String
    data = json.dumps(data)

    # Open the file, then save it
    try:
        file = open(filename, "wt")
    except:
        print("Failed to save the file.")
        return False
    else:
        file.write(data)
        file.close()
        return True

def loadData(filename):
    # Open the file, then load its contents
    try:
        file = open(filename, "rt")
    except:
        print("Failed to load the file.")
        return None
    else:
        data = file.read()
        file.close()

    # Data is a JSON string, so now we convert it back
    # to a Python Structure:
    data = json.loads(data)

    return data

# Get all price data
response = c.get_price_history_every_minute(symbol)
jsonData = response.json()

# Build prices and times list:
#
# As you're iterating over the same "candles" index on both loops
# when building those two lists, just reduce it to a single loop
prices = list()
times = list()
for i in range(len(jsonData["candles"])):
    prices.append(jsonData["candles"][i]["prices"])
    times.append(jsonData["candles"][i]["datetime"])

# Now, when you need, just save each list like this:
saveData("prices_list.json", prices)
saveData("times_list.json", times)


# And retrieve them back when you need it later:
prices = loadData("prices_list.json")
times = loadData("times_list.json")
```

Btw, pickle does the same thing, but it uses Binary Data instead of json, which is probably faster for save / load data. I don't know, didn't tested it.

In json, you have the advantage of readability, as you can open each file and read it directly, if you can understand JSON syntax.

Comment: I have no idea what kind of wizardry this is (I have been learning Python for about 6 days now) but it ran beautifully.  Parsing the JSON takes about a second, so I don't even really need to save the files, but when I do try to load them I get the following errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tradema_new.py", line 83, in <module>
    prices = loadData("prices_list.json")
  File "tradema_new.py", line 50, in loadData
    data = file.read()
io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Thank you so much for your help with this!

Comment: It took 2 mintutes and 14 seconds to parse the data from response.json and less than 1 second when moving the processing to json.data.

Thanks for that @Carl-HR

Comment: My Bad, the error was due to this line: `file = open(filename, "wt")`. The `wt` means "write text", so it created a blank file every time. I edited the code already to `file = open(filename, "rt")`. `rt` means "read text", so now it should work.

Comment: About the "I have no idea what kind of wizardry this is", to put it bluntly, this is not magic. It's the basics when dealing with any programming language. I recommend you to read and learn from many tutorials before doing any work on your own. If you don't understand what are `function definitions`, `file pointers`, or `data types` for example, you're going to face many other problems again.

Comment: Thanks again for all of your help and the advice Carl HR!  I have been reading non-stop over the last week or so, and find that my learning style is more hands on.  I retain a lot more information from trying to work though issues like the one you just helped me with, than I would if I read 5 tutorials or watched video walkthroughs.  The practical application and trial and error / research seem to work best for me.